# Getting unreachable code on my script block

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The "if" at the beginning of my script block inside the body is what keeps identifying as unreachable in Intellij. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCDO7.png)

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head><%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <style>
        <%@include file="/css/success.css" %>
    </style>
</head>
<Title>Logged In Successfully</Title>
<body>
<div class="message">
    <h2>${login.message}</h2>
</div>
    <script>
            if(${AdminCheck.adminCheck}  === true){
                document.write("<form action=\"http://example.com:8080/table\">" +
                    "<input class=\"showTable\" type=\"submit\" value=\"View Users\"/>" +
                    "</form>");
            }else{
                document.write("<form>\n" +
                    "\t<input class=\"adminVerification\" type=\"text\" id=\"verify\" name=\"adminVerification\" placeholder=\"Password\"/>\n" +
                "</form>");

                var check = document.getElementsByName("adminVerification");
                if(check.value === "IamADMIN"){
                    document.write("<form action=\"http://example.com:8080/table\">" +
                        "<input class=\"showTable\" type=\"submit\" value=\"View Users\"/>" +
                        "</form>");
                    document.getElementsByName("adminVerification").style.display="none";
                }
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** Turns out the script is running, I changed some of the conditional values to be redundantly true or false and they worked as they should. Still some weird analyzing from IntelliJ to say it's unreachable. Not sure why it would be throwing that.

Answer (score 0):

But does it run and IntelliJ is misidentifying it as unreachable? Or is it actually unreachable?

Also, the Title tag is outside both head and body, which might be confusing IntelliJ

Comment: I'm just a beginning developer so I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to front-end languages. However, it does run but my script is not functioning.